# Best mockup software for presenting the UX of a mobile app

Tags: mobile, tools, mockup, selling-ux

I'm looking for a mockup software that can very effectively communicate the overall design and UX of a mobile app.

Ideally it has these attributes:

- drag and drop elements (text boxes, check boxes, input fields, navigation, etc)
- allows for actual navigation through the app
- annotations to explain functionality
- web-based

I want to use this for initial presentations to remote clients around the world.

What are some recommendations you have?

Cheers!
Steve

Comment: Here's a related conversation: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46540/how-to-build-website-mockups-interface-design/46553#46553

Comment: Welcome to User Experience! Sorry, but questions requesting recommendations for books / software / apps / papers etc. would fall into the [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best software that i have come across and is highly looked up to in the industry is Axure Pro. You can make a fully working wireframe or mock up with click through

It is a little pricy but worth every penny. 
here is the link http://www.axure.com/

Comment: +1 on axure. You can easily export the wireframes/prototypes to a working web version, axure will even host it for you. If that's what you're after when you say "web-based"

Answer (score 0):

Try Keynote and the share link feature.  I just started using templates from http://keynotopia.com and have been very impressed with it.  These templates are designed for drag/drop building of interfaces in either PowerPoint or Keynote.